# How to prove a lemma required for the Banach Tarski Paradox?

Tags: geometry, rotations

I tried to teach myself the proof of the Banach Tarski Paradox by reading Terence Tao's paper on the subject; the link to the paper is here: https://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/preprints/Expository/banach-tarski.pdf

My question concerns Lemma 1.3.

Let $C$ be a countable subset of of $S^2$. Now if we choose a rotation $R$ from $SO(3)$ at random, then, with probability 1, we can say that $C, RC, R^2 C, R^3 C, \ldots$ are all disjoint sets. Why can we say this? How do we prove that such an $R$ are exists, and furthermore, that almost all elements of $SO(3)$ satisfy this condition? I can't seem to come up with any good reason for this.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, remember that "almost all" is measure-theoretic shorthand for "all but measure zero" - note that there is a natural measure on $SO(3)$, the "Haar measure" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure), so this makes sense.

With this in mind, the key to the proof of the lemma is the following standard result: the union of countably many measure-zero sets is measure zero. The argument goes as follows:

- Write $C$ as $\{c_i: i\in\mathbb{N}\}$; we can do this since $C$ is countable.
- Now, for $i, j, k, l\in\mathbb{N}$ with $i\not=k$, let $B_{i, j, k, l}$ be the set of *$(i, j)$-bad rotations*: $$B_{i, j, k, l}=\{R\in SO(3): R^i(c_j)=R^k(c_l)\}.$$ It's enough to show that each $B_{i, j, k, l}$ has measure zero.
- For simplicity, let's consider the case where $i=0, k=1$ - so we're trying to show that $B=\{R: c_j=R(c_l)\}$ has measure zero. But this is easy: either $l=j$, in which case $B$ is the set of rotations fixing $c_j$, which has measure zero; or $l\not=j$, in which case every element $b$ of $B$ can be written as a composition $b=f\circ g$, where $f$ is a fixed rotation sending $c_l$ to $c_j$ and $g$ is a rotation fixing $c_j$ (it doesn't matter what $f$ we choose, here), and since there are only measure-zero many such $g$, we know $B$ must have measure zero.
- The more general case of arbitrary $B_{i, j, k, l}$ is not much more complicated, so I leave it as an exercise.
- So each $B_{i, j, k, l}$ has measure zero, so the set $B_\infty=\bigcup B_{i, j, k, l}$ has measure zero; so its complement, $G$, has full measure. But by definition $G$ consists of all rotations $R$ such that for all $i, j, k, l$, with $i\not=k$, we have $R^i(c_j)\not=R^k(c_l)$. This is just a complicated way of saying that $G$ consists of all rotations $R$ such that for all $i\not=k$ we have $R^i(C)\cap R^k(C)=\emptyset$, that is, that $G$ is the set of all rotations with the desired property.

---

Technically there's a piece missing here - how do I know that the whole space $SO(3)$ doesn't have measure $0$? This is something we have to show, but for now it's probably best to just take it for granted.

Comment: How do you get "... there is exactly one rotation sending $c_l$ to $c_j$"? Whenever you have one such rotation you can post-compose it with any rotation that fixes $c_j$, of which there is an infinity (but still of measure zero).

Comment: @HenningMakholm Wow, yes, that's wildly wrong. Fixed. (Coffee taking longer to kick in than usual . . .)

Comment: ... and then you don't need to special-case $l=j$ anymore; you can just choose $f$ to be the identity.

Comment: Yes, that's redundant, but it's pedagogically easier to convince oneself of the special case $j=l$ first (at least, that's how it was for me).

Comment: If I randomly chose a circle on the sphere that contained both $c_l$ and $c_j$ and rotated by the axis perpendicular to that circle, there would be a rotation about that axis that sent $c_l$ to $c_j$. Is the set of rotations generated in this way the same as the set of rotations $f\circ g$ where $f$ and $g$ are as above?

Comment: I'm a little confused by Tao's language when he says "Pick $R$ at random... then with probability $1$, we can ensure that...". Is this just a weird way of saying, "Because the set ... has full measure, we can always choose $R$ such that ..." ? Or is there some insight from probability that I'm missing?